# Como usar Twisted no Mac OSX?

Tags: python, osx, console

Estou seguindo um tutorial para usar o Twisted para estabelecer conexão para um app.
Porem na hora de testar a conexão com o localhost para teste, parece que não está respondendo.

Estou usando o seguinte script no arquivo chatserver.py :

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print " um cliente conectado"

factory = Factory()
factory.protoco = IphoneChat
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

Então eu abro outra janela do console para testar com o seguinte comando:

```
telnet localhost 80
```

E me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Trying ::1... telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
>   Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection
>   refused telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Como consigo fazer o Twisted funcionar no Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha primeira sugestão é sempre que você escolha em outra porta, como `8000`. No OSX normalmente só processos executados com **root** podem abrir portas abaixo de 1024. Isso pode ser mudado mas eu não recomendo.

Se você realmente precisar usar a porta `80`, o OSX vem com um utilitário chamado **ipfw** que permite redirecionar a porta `80` para a `8000`:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8000 tcp from any to me 80
```

Agora você pode mudar seu programa para a porta `8000` e ainda assim acessá-lo na porta `80`.